# Where to see baseball in Daegu, South Korea?

Tags: south-korea, sport

I am lucky enough to be in Daegu, South Korea this weekend. I'd like to bring my son to see some baseball while we are there. What are the options?

I already found that the [Samsung Lions](https://www.samsunglions.com/index.asp) play in Daegu, but unfortunately, they will be out of town this weekend.

Is there any other baseball to be seen in Daegu? Any level would be fun, from little league up to minor league baseball, and anything in between.

Comment: It's worth looking at other Korean cities too: Seoul is two hours away by KTX train and Busan less than 1 hour.

Comment: On the KTX, you'd be in Busan before you could even board the plane to the US.  Bullet trains are amazing, try one sometime!

Comment: @lambshaanxy The question is about where to find baseball inside of Daegu, a city of more than 2 million people. While finding baseball in Busan or another city is a worthy question, that's not really what I'm asking here.

Comment: Daegu may have 2 million people but it only has one KBO team.  If you'd like to bring your son to see some (pro-level) baseball *and* it has to be this weekend, your only option is to travel elsewhere in Korea.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Please read the last paragraph of my question.